# gpg: how to decrypt multiple files to /dev/null?

Tags: gpg

I'd like to decrypt multiple files at once and check gpg status in order to verify their consistency. The problem is that --output option doesn't work with --multiline argument and normal STDOUT redirection is ignored.

```
find -name '*.gpg' | gpg --multifile --decrypt >/dev/null
```

Redirection ignored. Normal files are created.

```
>find -name '*.gpg' | gpg --multifile --decrypt --output=/dev/null
gpg: --output doesn't work for this command
```

How to achieve this goal with single gpg call?

Comment: Try find -name '*.gpg' -execdir gpg --multifile --decrypt > /dev/null

Comment: @RamanSailopal Did you actually read the question?

Comment: Is it important that it is a single call to GPG? It seems that calling GPG multiple times would also be a valid way to achieve the goal of checking that the files are consistent.

Comment: How about the `-d` argument? as in `gpg --multifile -d $(find -name '*.gpg') > /dev/null`

Comment: @RalphRönnquist `-d` is the same as `--decrypt`.

Comment: `man gpg` suggests about `-d`, that "This command differs from the default  operation, as it never writes to the filename which is included in the file,..."

Comment: @RalphRönnquist However, the same manual shows that `-d` is the same as `--decrypt`, and `gpg --help` agrees. _shrug_

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Bash >= 4.0:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/*.gpg; do
  gpg --decrypt --output=/dev/null "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `gpg --decrypt` once per file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gpg' \
    -exec gpg --decrypt --output /dev/null {} ';'
```

The `--output` option is incompatible with `--multifile`.